# How do I get CORS to work for images loaded from Cloudfront and server running NGINX?

Tags: nginx, cors, amazon-cloudfront, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I'm trying to figure out how to properly get CORS to work on all the images for our site - so that we can cache them using WorkBox for PWA that I'm building.

Our current setup is as follows -

I've my main site running on `https://www.MyAwesomeSite.com` and I've configured AWS Cloudfront to serve all our static assets (js,css and images) through URL `https://data.MyAwesomeSite.com/`.

My PWA is almost ready - except that the `opaque` responses (all images from Cloudfront) are blowing the cache size as expected. That is while the actual cache size is ~200KB - Chrome reports it to be around 300 - 400 MB.

While investigating the issue, I found out that Workbox may sometime Cache the Opaque responses which causes the Cache size issue.

After reading multiple posts and articles about CORS - I'm still not sure if I need to enable CORS on NGINX running on my server OR configure it on Cloudfront.

## My First Approach:

I tried enabling CORS on my NGINX server by following the guide on:https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html . However, using the code as-is resulted into entire site showing 404 error.

In order to investigate this new issue, I found out that `if` blocks inside `location` are not reliable and are not recommended. I tried using `maps` function, but it did not work. My final approach to enabling CORS on my NGIX is this -

```
server {

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 http2 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    root /path/to/my/files;
    server_name www.MyAwesomeSite.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,User-Agent,DNT,Cache-Control,X-Mx-ReqToken';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    client_max_body_size 32M;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

# Rest of the configuration
```

While I'm not sure if this approach is correct - and whether it actually is the right way to do it; I do see the new headers in the regular GET requests for views being loaded from my server

## My Second Approach

I then tried setting up CORS on my Cloudfront with the help of AWS Tech Support and it seems to be working as expected.

Then in order to tackle my original problem, I followed Google's recommendation to add `crossorigin="anonymous"` to all the image tags on my site.

### But this leads to a new problem!

With `crossorigin="anonymous` added to all the images; I found out that Chrome would randomly vanish images stating No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers were present on the response.

My main problems are as follows -

1. None of my images are being loaded via XHR requests. Do I still need CORS; and if I do - should I enable it on my NGINX or Cloudfront?
2. How do I ensure caching of image assets for my PWA without really blowing up the cache?
3. Am I missing out on anything important?

I'd really be thankful to anyone who helps me with this issue. I'm trying to figure this out since last 72 hours without any success.

Answer (score 1):

The origin you're accessing from a different origin needs to enable cross-origin requests.

That is, your CloudFront config for `data.myawesomesite.com` needs to have the appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers, and related headers if necessary, to allow requests from sites loaded from `www.myawesomesite.com` if you expect to read that data in script.

Comment: Cloudfront config or data.myawesomesite.com does have CORS headers; but when I add `crossorigin="anonymous"` to the images in my html; then image loading behavior is random; that is some just don't appear; and appear on refresh. This is the most confusing part.